# Lectures TOC in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have a large beamer presentation split in 10 lectures.
Each lecture has sections.
Is there a way to create a kind of TOC of only the lectures in a slide ?

```
\documentclass[handout,11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{All lectures}
%    \tableofLectures  as a list of all lectures
\end{frame}

\lecture{Lecture1}{lec1}
    \section{1}
    \section{2}
 \lecture{Lecture2}{lec2}
    \section{1}
 \section{2}
\lecture{Lecture3}{lec3} 
    \section{1}
 \section{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @samcarter I just updated my basic MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the lecture names to the toc by adding the via `\addtocontents{toc}{...}` in the definition of `\lecture`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{lecture in toc}{parent=structure}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@lecture[#1]#2#3{%
  \beamer@savemode
  \mode<all>%
  \refstepcounter{lecture}%
  \def\beamer@currentlecturelabel{#3}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\beamer@currentlecturelabel
  \def\beamer@lecturename{#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortlecturename{#1}%
  \ifx\beamer@onlylecture\@empty
  \else
    \expandafter\beamer@if@in@clist@TF\expandafter\beamer@onlylecture
      \expandafter{\beamer@currentlecturelabel}%
      {\beamer@inlecturetrue}%
      {\beamer@inlecturefalse}%
  \fi
  \beamer@atbeginlecture
  \beamer@resumemode
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{lecture in toc}%
    \vfill%
    #2%
  }
}
\makeatother

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
  \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=hide/hide,subsectionstyle=hide/hide/hide]
\end{frame}

\lecture{Lecture1}{lec1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1a}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 1b}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 1c}
\frame{}

\section{Section 2}
\frame{}

\lecture{Lecture2}{lec2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3a}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3b}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3c}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

To prevent the lectures to appear in the normal toc, one could create a custom list of lectures (`lol` for short :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{lecture in toc}{parent=structure}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@lecture[#1]#2#3{%
  \beamer@savemode
  \mode<all>%
  \refstepcounter{lecture}%
  \def\beamer@currentlecturelabel{#3}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\beamer@currentlecturelabel
  \def\beamer@lecturename{#2}%
  \def\beamer@shortlecturename{#1}%
  \ifx\beamer@onlylecture\@empty
  \else
    \expandafter\beamer@if@in@clist@TF\expandafter\beamer@onlylecture
      \expandafter{\beamer@currentlecturelabel}%
      {\beamer@inlecturetrue}%
      {\beamer@inlecturefalse}%
  \fi
  \beamer@atbeginlecture
  \beamer@resumemode
  \addtocontents{lol}{%
    \protect\usebeamercolor[fg]{lecture in toc}%
    #2%
    \vfill%
  }
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \clearpage
  \if@filesw
      \newwrite\tf@lol
      \immediate\openout\tf@lol\jobname.lol\relax
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{multicol}

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Agenda}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
                \tiny
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
        \end{multicols}
    \end{frame}
    \frame{\sectionpage} 
}

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vfill
\IfFileExists{\jobname.lol}{\input{\jobname.lol}}{}
\end{frame}

\lecture{Lecture1}{lec1}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1a}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 1b}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 1c}
\frame{}

\section{Section 2}
\frame{}

\lecture{Lecture2}{lec2}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3a}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3b}
\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 3c}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you @samcarter. I ran your code and it works smoothly. however, I use a partial toc at the beginning of each section as in
\AtBeginSection[]
{
 \begin{frame}
  {Agenda}
  \hfill
  \parbox[t]{0.97\textwidth}
  {
   \begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\textwidth}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
     \tiny{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}
    \end{multicols}
   \end{minipage}
  }  
 \end{frame}
 \frame{\sectionpage}
}
And i have the name of the lectures inserted now.
How shall I restrict this to happen ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Oh, that makes things a lot more complicated. At the moment I'm not sure how to solve this, I'll have to think about it

Comment: Thank you @samcarter . Glad to read you think it’s not trivial :) a bientôt

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Please see my edit

Comment: it seems that jobname.lol is not found. Am at work but i'll investigate why. Merci !

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Did you compile two times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88580/discussion-between-julien-elie-taieb-and-samcarter).